# Azure Logic APP resume work flow after web hook call

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am setting up a work flow with web hook URL.

Following are the steps we have configured.

1. Http Request is received.
2. Send Email with Gmail plugin
3. Response 200
4. WebHook Call back to Application
5. **Resume WorkFlow** to continue other operations ( Ex. Send Email With
   outlook configuration)

Do have faced problem to resume work flow after web-hook URL is successfully executed.

[Logic app run history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRkU0.png)

[Run History flow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQgds.png)

Image shows request still in request state after web-hook URL Called. Unable to resume logic app workflow after webhook URL.

Please lets me any workaround to resolve this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not enough information for us to be able to help. Does the WebHook complete successfully? Do you have control of what happens there? Why is control not given back to the Logic App? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please share the flow picture and click the run history and show the details about which step it stuck in.

Comment: Thanks guys. Do have added Run History flow image for more clarity

Comment: Your webhook action is still waiting to be triggered. how do you call back the logic app ?

Comment: how do you call back the logic app ?. Unfortunately that's the issue I am facing, my web hook is returning HTTP status 200. So i expect work flow to resume after Webhook returning 200 status with further execution.

Comment: Unfortunately logic app work flow is allowing a single HTTP trigger in the  Work flow, cannot resume work flow with another trigger. Is their any limitations?.